# Nested components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, components, vue.js

I struggle in creating nested components where each layer includes templates:

```
<wizard>
    <step name="first">Do this step first!</step>
    <step name="second">This should follow</step>
</wizard>
```

(full example: http://jsfiddle.net/maxhq/9o4qxd7t/)

I only get templates to work *either* for parent *or* for child components, never for both.

- if parent has no template and is used with `<... inline-template>`, child components (and their templates) are evaluated (like in http://jsfiddle.net/hajkrupo/3/)
- if parent includes a template (even with special tag `<content>`), then the child components do not get inserted/evaluated

Can this be solved in vue.js?

Comment: I believe that this is your problem [http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content_Insertion](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content_Insertion): "transcluded contents are compiled in the parent component’s scope, not in the child’s scope".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest vue.js version (1.0.26 at the time of writing) your problem is using `<content></content>` as the syntax was changed to `<slot></slot>`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9o4qxd7t/32/)

Answer (score 0):

No. `inline-template` means you define template inline there there:

> When this param is present, the component will use its inner content as its template rather than transclusion content. This allows more flexible template-authoring.

You can do it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/8k335nrf/

Comment: It can't be solved? That makes me weep a bit :-( I know I can write it the way you showed, but then the markup that I like to see as internal to the component has to be exposed to the "outside" world.